# How to align columns in one dataframe to the same order of the columns in a diff dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 166 columns & 63k rows that is in a specific order.
I have a second dataframe of 166 columns & 35k rows.
The 166 columns in the second dataframe are not in the same order as the first dataframe.

How do I force the second dataframe to align with the column order of the first dataframe? (The 166 columns are the same names in both dataframes).

When googling for a solution one method came up:

`df2 = df2[['col1','col2','col3','col4']]`

But there are 161 columns and this would be too tedious.

```py
X_18 #dataframe 1
X_19 #dataframe 2

# I tried to re-order both on the same conditions using the following code:

X_18.columns.sort_values()
X_19.columns.sort_values()
```

I expected the column names to be in the same order, but when comparing the two after applying sort on both it appears the order was not alphabetical.

Example:

```
DataFrame1-Index(['Example 1','Example 2','Example 3'
       ...
       'Example 55','Example 23'],
      dtype='object', length=161)

DataFrame2-Index(['Example 1','Example 2','Example 3'
       ...
       'Example 45','Example 33'],
      dtype='object', length=161)
```

Comment: just do `X_19 = X_19[X_18.columns]` or vice versa

Comment: `df1.reindex(df2.columns, axis=1)`. ensures `df1` has the same columns as `df2`

Comment: But if the columns *are* unique and perfectly overlap, then a simple sort on both should do it: `df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=1)`. But you may want to check with the above two methods. Missing keys will raise errors, or lead to all NaN columns.

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy - thanks! Does this also maintain the values of each row or would only the column name change?

Comment: NP and yes, my answer and the ones below both keep the values intact. My answer is simply using slicing, you slice the dataframe to specific columns and that ordering of the columns is kept. If a column in `X_18` is not in `X_19` the code will raise a `KeyError` so it's kinda safe

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy - Understood, thank you for the clear explanation, this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approach. As I guess that you want to have columns naturally sorted 'col9', 'col10', 'col11' etc you can use natsorted for each of dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from natsort import natsorted

df = df.reindex(natsorted(df.columns)), axis=1)
```